# Comma in "The key objective is X, with the broader goal of Y"

Tags: punctuation, commas

> The key objective of the declaration is to create guidelines, with the broader goal of facilitating international mobility of students.

Are there any rules that govern the placement or omission of this comma?

Answer (score 1):

'The key objective of the declaration is to create guidelines, with the broader goal of facilitating international mobility of students.'

The purpose of the comma is to separate the prepositional phrase from *guidelines.*  Everything from *with* to the period works as a sort of clarification that applies to the entire sentence, and, more specifically, it belongs to *key objective*.

i.e. The key objective is both to create guidelines and to facilitate the international mobility of students.  Without the comma, one may mistake it to mean 'The key objective of the declaration is to create guidelines; the guidelines have the broader goal of facilitating international mobility of students.'

Answer (score 0):

You are joining two sentences. If the comma wasn't there it would read "... to create guidelines with ..." and seem like the rest of the sentence would be about the guidelines.

The comma adds a pause when you're reading the sentence. If it causes ambiguity or confusion when read without a pause, use a comma.

Comment: So 'The key objective of the declaration is to create guidelines, with the broader goal of facilitating international mobility of students.' = 'The broader goal of the declaration is facilitating the international mobility of students; within this remit, the key objective is to create guidelines to achieve this.' // 'The key objective of the declaration is to create guidelines with the broader goal of facilitating international mobility of students.' = The key objective of the declaration is to create guidelines whose broader goal is the facilitating of international mobility of students.'

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. The phrase after the comma cannot be removed without changing the meaning of the first sentence. For this reason, I would argue the comma is incorrectly placed.

Comment: More to the point, the phrase after the comma is just that: a phrase. It is not a sentence. So the analysis in the first sentence of this answer is incorrect.